# How can I simultaneously run a timer and another function, reacting to what time does the timer return? [Python]

Tags: python, timer, python-multithreading, simultaneous

I have a timer, returning(at least I hope it does) some value. I have a function, outside timer class, which should look at timer's returned value and if that function receives specific data - does something else, only at that specific moment.

```
from time import time, sleep

class Clock:
    def __init__(self):
        self.oneSec = 0
        self.secsPassed = 0 #counts all seconds that already passed, up to 59; then resets and counts again
        self.minute = 0
        self.hour = 0 #currently unused
        self.day = 0 #currently unused
        self.start_time = 0

        self.start()

    def start(self):
        while self.secsPassed < 10:
            self.start_time = time()
            sleep(1)
            self.oneSec = int(time() - self.start_time) #easiest way to measure a second
            self.secsPassed += self.oneSec
            print(f"{self.minute} minutes, {self.secsPassed} seconds")
            self.getStats() #returns values without breaking the loop, at least I hope it does 

            if self.secsPassed == 10: #normally it'd be 59, but I wanted to do it quicker for sake of tests
                self.secsPassed = -1 #with 0 after 1:59 minute there would be immediately 2:01
                self.minute += 1

            if self.minute == 2 and self.secsPassed == 0: #just to end test if everything works fine
                break #for some reason it doesn't totally exit whole code, only stops counting, but I still have to manually exit the code from running


    def getStats(self):
        return self.day, self.hour, self.minute, self.secsPassed
```

Now I need a function, outside Clock class, that can observe how the return statements of my Clock change and react to them accordingly. I already have done some coding, but it can't work and I probably know why, but I couldn't for 3 hours come up with a solution. Here's my current code:

```
def clockChecker(clock):
    while True: #I thought it'd be a good idea to loop since it has to be "conscious" the whole time to react on new returns, but... I guess this cannot work, after a few hours I realized that by running this function it gets the returned statement only once, so it can't update
        if clock == (0, 0, 0, 3): #if clocks makes 3rd second
            print("It works!")
            break
```

I tried playing with threading, pipes, and pools, but if my clockChecker is invalid, nothing will help.
First I definitely need help with my clockChecker, second I'd appreciate help with at least choosing which one(threading, pipes, pools) should I use, so it works quite smoothly.

Comment: just use threading ... `if clock.getStats() == (0, 0, 0, 3)` I guess

Answer (score 0):

There are a few difficulties you will find with your approach.

The first is simply the `clockChecker` function, I believe you are missing a `.getStats()` call to make that work, it has no chance of success.

Even with this change (which should work), an exact match is pretty dangerous, and will suffer from both "not matching at the right time" and "perhaps never matching".

One way to deal with this is to use `>=` or other conditions that will match more than a specific instant.  Others include: `threading.Event`; hooks with conditions pushed into the timer; executing your logic as-is with a sleep for three seconds; coroutines, and more :)

Comment: Well, I simply put there clock without .getStats(), because at initialization it uses start() method, which includes getStats() every "cycle" it makes.

Comment: @GotConfused - your comment to that line is `at least I hope it does` ...

Comment: well, technically it should work, at least it worked as I checked it, but after that I've made maany changes so now I'm not that sure

Comment: Sorry @GotConfused, it really won't work like that.  You end up having lines that don't do anything (as if you typed `(0, 0, 0, 0)` where your `getStats()` is), and busy loops that `while True` over a constant.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont mind changing to another route

```py
def outside_func():
    do something
    return

class clock():
    def __init__(self, arguments):
        self.secspassed
    def timer():
        while True:
            self.secspasswd += 1
            if self.secspasswd % 3 == 0:
                outside_func()
            time.sleep(1)
```

I think use +1 second to set time value would ceate increasing bias.
Programmed +1 need some time, set attribute value need some time also. Real time has passed longer than 1 second when you +1,

Answer (score 0):

print format is modified because I use python 3.5

```
from time import time, sleep
import threading 

class Clock:
    def __init__(self):
        self.oneSec = 0
        self.secsPassed = 0 #counts all seconds that already passed, up to 59; then resets and counts again
        self.minute = 0
        self.hour = 0 #currently unused
        self.day = 0 #currently unused
        self.start_time = 0

        #self.start()

    def start(self):
        while self.secsPassed < 10:
            self.start_time = time()
            sleep(1)
            self.oneSec = int(time() - self.start_time) #easiest way to measure a second
            self.secsPassed += self.oneSec
            print("%d minutes, %d seconds"%(self.minute,self.secsPassed,))
            # self.getStats() #returns values without breaking the loop, at least I hope it does 

            if self.secsPassed == 10: #normally it'd be 59, but I wanted to do it quicker for sake of tests
                self.secsPassed = -1 #with 0 after 1:59 minute there would be immediately 2:01
                self.minute += 1

            if self.minute == 2 and self.secsPassed == 0: #just to end test if everything works fine
                break #for some reason it doesn't totally exit whole code, only stops counting, but I still have to manually exit the code from running


    def getStats(self):
        return self.day, self.hour, self.minute, self.secsPassed



def clockChecker(clock):
    while True: #I thought it'd be a good idea to loop since it has to be "conscious" the whole time to react on new returns, but... I guess this cannot work, after a few hours I realized that by running this function it gets the returned statement only once, so it can't update
        if clock.getStats() == (0, 0, 0, 3): #if clocks makes 3rd second
            print("It works!")
            break
        sleep(1)
clock=Clock()

th1=threading.Thread(target=lambda: clock.start())
th1.start()

th2=threading.Thread(target=clockChecker,args=(clock,))
th2.start()

th2.join()
th1.join()
```